# Are Classes that implement an interface only with no other methods ok?

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, interface, uml

Is this scenario OK or have I misunderstood something along the way?

I have a superclass with some protected variables and some accessor methods. Then I have 3 subclasses that inherit from the superclass, each with new and different variables and associated accessors (Obviously this is OK so far). Then I have an interface consisting of only one method and no variables which is implemented by all the classes differently to process their variables and return an answer.

I'm using an interface rather than just a virtual method in the superclass as I need to call this method from other unrelated classes in the program to return different processed data.

Sorry if this is a silly question I am very new to C# and still learning a lot and need to confirm my understanding before I can move on. I'm unsure if this is the best way to do this because all the classes here have no other methods aside from accessors and the interface's method. Is there a better way I should be doing this as classes with no methods (other than the interface and accessors) seem a bit wrong?

Comment: FWIW, this is far from a silly question. An interface with one method is fine. This question (and a good answer) could easily be a book.

Comment: I think it's a perfectly reasonable question. Having such an interface is acceptable (actually, Microsoft themselves provides several such interfaces, such as IDisposable).

Comment: Thanks guys I was a little worried I was going the long way round the problem.

Comment: this question is oddly worded and referential.. "with no other methods"..? other?.. what determines a method as "other", and what's the alternative to other? by description alone it seems you're determining other methods as being more then one?.. so the title ought to be "an interface that has only one method".. ??

Comment: sorry, I meant to say welcome to SO first... also, asking whether something is "ok" is asking for a subjective answer, which will promote general discussion and discords.  but here it's probably not much of a problem given the subject..

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You're on the right track. Have the the superclass inherit the interface, then provide implementation for it in the subclasses.

```
abstract class Item : GameObject, ISellable
{ 
}

class GenericLoot : Item {
    public int BasePrice { get; }
}

class Slave : Person, ISellable {
    public int BasePrice { get; }
}
```

... A little dark, but you get the idea.

Long answer: Organize your classes by thoughtful abstraction of objects in the context of your problem. It's A-OK to define an abstract class with only a concrete subclass, or a subclass with NO body. Just so long as you stay true to the nature of the objects involved.

```
abstract class Person {}

abstract class PlayerCharacter : Person {}

class Batman : PlayerCharacter {}
```